# What does "stood on his head" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I am confused about the following sentence:

> Hegel was a german philosopher who Marx '**stood on his head**'

I can't seem to find a proper definition for this phrase. What does "stood on his head" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Hegel or Marx, but the usual meaning in a context like this, is that Marx took Hegel's ideas and used them to reach a completely opposite conclusion. In this sense, Hegel's ideas were overturned, just as if he were literally standing on his head.

Comment: Good answer, but could you elaborate with examples of how to use the idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 2):

To **stand on one's head** is to be upside down - doing a [handstand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handstand) or a [headstand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headstand).

To **stand something on *its* head** is to *turn it upside down*.

We use the expression metaphorically, as *stand X on its head* or *turn X on its head*, to metaphorically turn it upside down - take the same elements and put them in a different order to produce a very different, possibly even a contradictory meaning.

Sometimes it's more literal, as we might "turn a dessert on its head" by arranging its components in a different order - though not necessarily literally reversed. By saying Mark stood Hegel on his head, we mean that Marx took the components of Hegel's philosophy and rearranged them to reach a very different conclusion.

This [review of a reinterpreted ballet](https://www.questia.com/newspaper/1P2-39257716/tchaikovsky-turned-on-his-head-a-choreographer-uses) gives an interesting example with pretty good exploration and explanation.

Your example sentence isn't quite idiomatic, though. We wouldn't usually put a metaphor like that in quote marks.

Comment: It's a quote often attributed to Marx himself. Another version has Marx saying that he "found Hegel standing on his head and stood him back on his feet."

Comment: Ah. Either the non-native-English-speaking of Marx, or the age and thus slight differences in language, would contribute to it not being quite how I would expect it to be said, and the fact it's a quotation explains the quotation marks. Not obvious without the background knowledge or more context, though ;)

Comment: I've been unable to find the source of this anecdote, and can't say whether Marx said it in English or German or French. But the use of *stand* where we'd most likely say *set* today isn't entirely obsolete yet.

Comment: No, not entirely by any means, just distinctly less in my experience.